# Formula to get uniform grid size for 2D point cloud

Tags: algorithm

Lets say one has a study area A with n 2D points scattered throughout (one can assume the points are randomly distributed).  I want to know if there is a formula that one can use to determine the approximate size (size for each individual cell) of a uniform 2D grid so that each cell will contain on average x points.  The grid will be axis aligned.

Comment: By definition, if N cells contain M points, then each cell contains M/N points on the average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general no, because you data might be biased in arbitrary ways.
If you have truly random distribution (uniform) than any uniform grid that has `n/x` cells of equal area will be good (the distribution guarantees that you get approximately the same number of points in each cell). Just make sure the grid covers the point distribution area correctly (if all your points are [0, 1] your grid should cover [0, 1] not [0, 100]).

If you want axis align with the same number of cells in each direction then you should have a grid of `sqrt(n/x)` cells by `sqrt(n/x)` cells.